# Why can't one find UV LEDs with wavelength under 280 nm?

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes

Recently, I read about the excellent property of the UV light to kill a lot of bacteria and then I found out that low wavelength (<280 nm) kills more bacteria than at higher wavelength, which makes sense. I checked then online to see if one can find LED's that can go to such a small wavelength, but I couldn't find any. I found quite a lot of commercial already made devices that are recommended for killing bacteria, but not so many technical details about the wavelength.

Going beyond the commercial part, I was wondering if there is any technical limitation to producing such LEDs? If so, what would the restrictions be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-wavelength LEDs are hard to make, mainly because the wavelength of LEDs is inversely proportional to the bandgap of the material, and it's hard to make LEDs out of materials with large bandgaps; this is such a challenging task that the creation of [blue LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Blue_and_ultraviolet) earned the 2014 Nobel prize in physics.

That said, Wikipedia does [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Colors_and_materials) several semiconductors that can in principle emit in the UV range you're interested in, so one useful starting point can be to look for LEDs based on those specific materials. I wouldn't hold my breath, because

1. UV LEDs are likely harder than blue ones, but
2. there isn't the huge market that blue LEDs have, so there's much less incentive to work away at those problems,

but in principle it's all just materials-science semi-engineering-type challenges.

A brief look for LEDs from those materials yields e.g. [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature04760), which is probably a good litmus test for how the field is: the problem is solvable enough, but it might still be a while before they're widely available on a commercial scale.